# Realm Swift Composite Keys for Optional Properties

Tags: swift, realm

Is there any way I could make composite keys for a Realm class with optional properties?

for example:

```
class Item: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    let importantNumber = RealmOptional<Int>()
    let importantNumber2 = RealmOptional<Int>()

    func setCompoundID(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
    }

    func setCompoundImportantNumber(importantNumber: Int) {
        self.importantNumber = importantNumber
        compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
    }

    func setCompoundImportantNumber2(importantNumber2: Int) {
        self.importantNumber2 = importantNumber2
        compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
    }

    dynamic lazy var compoundKey: String = self.compoundKeyValue()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "compoundKey"
    }

    func compoundKeyValue() -> String {
        return "\(id)\(importantNumber)\(importantNumber2)"
    }
}
```

When I write my code like this, the compiler complains that I can't assign to my constant properties and it recommends me changing 'let' to 'var'; however, according to the [Realm Swift Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#optional-properties), I need to have optional properties set as constants.

I'm not sure if this is even possible because I can't find anything in the Realm documentation about optional primary keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `RealmOptional`'s `value` member. `RealmOptional` properties cannot be `var` because Realm can't detect assignment to property types that cannot be represented by the Objective-C runtime, which is why `RealmOptional`, `List` and `LinkingObjects` properties must all be `let`.

```
class Item: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0
    let importantNumber = RealmOptional<Int>()
    let importantNumber2 = RealmOptional<Int>()

    func setCompoundID(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
        compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
    }

    func setCompoundImportantNumber(importantNumber: Int) {
        self.importantNumber.value = importantNumber
        compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
    }

    func setCompoundImportantNumber2(importantNumber2: Int) {
        self.importantNumber2.value = importantNumber2
        compoundKey = compoundKeyValue()
    }

    dynamic lazy var compoundKey: String = self.compoundKeyValue()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "compoundKey"
    }

    func compoundKeyValue() -> String {
        return "\(id)\(importantNumber)\(importantNumber2)"
    }
}
```